# Bootstrap input text size is not the same in Firefox or Chrome

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, firefox

I have an input text with a size (10) and a maxlength (20) in a form-inline form.
I use an edited bootstrap css.

In Chrome I can see more characters (10) in the input text than in Firefox (only 8).
I prefer what Chrome display.
What do I have to do to have the same behavior in Firefox as in Chrome?

Example in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x646ruqs/4/

```
<FORM class="form-inline" name="form1">
<input size="10" maxlength="20" name="nm1dis" value="WZWZWZWZWZWZWZWZWZWZ"  id="nm1dis" class="form-control input-xs " type="text">
</FORM>
```

Thank you.

Comment: You have a huge big reset stylesheet, but you never set the input's width anywhere.

Comment: I was hoping the auto width size to work the same in firefox and chrome. Nothing I can do here except set a fixed width?

Comment: Yes, that's what a reset stylesheet is for!